# How to use IMPORTXML on Angular site?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to learn more about `IMPORTXML` function in Google Sheets. Currently, I am facing an issue with one site that I think use angular

Previously I have been able to get some date from other sites. However, it seems to me that it might be some special tricks when it comes to Angular.

I am trying to read data from this site: http://ibindex.se/ibi/#/index
The only thing that I can fetch is currently the image in the header

Anyone here who is more experienced and can give me some input?